# How can you create a variable shared between methods in a jQuery 'on' object?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have some logic both on hover and when the user left (and maybe clicked inside the window) the hovered element:

```
jQuery('.element').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
    },
    mouseleave: function() {

    }
});
```

The problem is that, for each method, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, I'd have to re-initialize common variables I'm interested in, for example `jQuery(this)` to refer to the current element I'm working with.

I understand they're both different events, but where is the common ground that can be used-manipulated so I don't have to copy logic / re-initialize variables?

I'm looking to do something like (I know it's not correct syntax, but I'd need a constructor of some sorts):

```
jQuery('.element').on(
    let shared_variable = jQuery(this), {
    mouseenter: function() {
    },
    mouseleave: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: The variable would go before the `on()`, but given what you are wanting the variable to do in this case, it doesn't make sense.  As the `this` of the element that was interacted with, would not exist until the event happened.  Otherwise, if you want the variable to contains all the `$('.element')` then just put `var whatever = ` in front of that whole statement.

Comment: @Taplar That's exactly my issue. Obviously, it's trivial to just add a variable before, but I want that variable to be generated at "event time", inside the handler. Is it not possible?

Comment: You would have to do something like the answer below.  Otherwise, as I said, you can't have a variable for the element that the event happened on *before* the event happens.

Comment: if the actual variable you want is `this` then it will be the same in both cases as `this` is bound to the element the event was triggered on.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Correct! But the problem here is that I'd like to use that `this` as a jQuery object shared between both instances without having to do `jQuery(this)` inside each event.

Comment: why though ? it is really inexpensive to just do `$(this)` in both handlers. Unless  you just want to know if it can be done for academic purposes. Otherwise, for this specific case, it is a bit of an overkill to go the other way just to create a shared variable.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I agree, I'm trying to find what approach yields better performance and then dig deeper as to why. I'm thinking, if I don't have to initialize an object twice, but once, that's a gain, even if small. It's not to optimize prematurely, rather to learn how to code in a certain manner that it's both fast and readable. Plus, in my opinion, it doesn't make sense to initialize it twice. If you can provide anything in this direction, I'll gladly read and try to apply.

Comment: jquery does not do much when you pass a node (*and `this` refers to the node*). See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L103-L106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have just *one* hander, bound to multiple events, then define the common variables in the handler, check which event triggered it, and call the appropriate other function:

```js
const handlers = {
  mouseenter($this, shared) {
    $this.css('background-color', shared);
  },
  mouseleave($this, shared) {
    $this.css('background-color', '');
  }
}
jQuery('.element').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
  const $this = jQuery(this);
  const shared = 'yellow';
  handlers[e.type]($this, shared);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">hover</div>
```

You can also define the object inside the handler to avoid having to pass variables around, but it's a bit inelegant even though it requires less code:

```js
jQuery('.element').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
  const handlers = {
    mouseenter() {
      $this.css('background-color', shared);
    },
    mouseleave() {
      $this.css('background-color', '');
    }
  };
  const $this = jQuery(this);
  const shared = 'yellow';
  handlers[e.type]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">hover</div>
```

If you have many such common variables, you might consider using an object containing those common variables instead:

```js
const handlers = {
  mouseenter({ $this, shared1 }) {
    $this.css('background-color', shared1);
  },
  mouseleave({ $this, shared2 }) {
    $this.css('background-color', shared2);
  }
}
jQuery('.element').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
  const shared = 'yellow';
  const sharedParams = {
    $this: jQuery(this),
    shared1: 'yellow',
    shared2: 'orange'
  };
  handlers[e.type](sharedParams);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">hover</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is why I'll never finish learning JS. Any documentation / patterns that I can learn about to understand why this, in my eyes, fuckery, works?

Comment: The key here is that, with jQuery, you can handle multiple events in a single `.on`, which you'd just have to know or read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) about beforehand - after that, it's just defining variables and passing them around to functions, which is quite plain, I don't know if there's a name for this sort of thing. (You can also handle multiple events in a single handler with `addEventListener`, actually, it just takes another line)

Comment: The code just seems weird due to my lack of familiarity. Basically what we're doing is setting the events, `mouseenter mouseleave`, creating two functions with the same names for each, then, we initialize our shared variables and then retroactively go back and execute the function that matches `e.type` at the time an event is happening, correct?

Comment: `handlers` is effectively a map, where the key is the function name that matches the event name, and the value is the callback that should process that event.

Comment: @Taplar Got it. My goal here is to learn but my intentions are to optimize speed. I will test what works faster, but in your experience, is this worth doing over just re-initializing each variable for each event, as in my original approach?

Comment: This is just my opinion, but unless you have a reason to do it, it doesn't really make sense.  In either case of forcing it to share variables or not, you are going to be doing `$(this)` in both cases.  But with forcing shared variables, you've introduced much more logic.

Comment: @coolpasta Speed is rarely something to worry about when writing code - in most cases, code readability and understandability is more important. Once you have logic that works, you can run a performance check to see exactly where the CPU-intensive operations are, and try to optimize them, but don't try to prematurely optimize (except for the sake of computational complexity, perhaps). If speed really is an issue, consider using standard DOM methods rather than jQuery, there's nothing jQuery can do that standard Javascript can't do faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) **data** parameter?

```js
var yourObject = {color: 1};

$('.element').on('mouseenter', yourObject, function(e) {
    var x = e.data.color;
    console.log(e.type + ' --> ' + x);
    e.data.color += 1;
});

$('.element').on('mouseleave',  yourObject, function(e) {
    var x = e.data.color;
    console.log(e.type + ' --> ' + x);
    e.data.color += 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">hover</div>
```

Comment: Because I'm trying to handle different logic for each event separately while still having shared variables.

Comment: @coolpasta Snippet updated. One object and two event listeners. Let me know..... Thanks

Comment: This also works, but semantically, I liked the original approach from my question. A shared object would've been the easy and probably best way out, but at least for readability, having the logic coupled within a `{}` makes it instantly obvious that it's "oh, if this, do this, if not, do that". But now that I look at the accepted answer, while correct & beautiful, it's more complex than this.

Comment: @coolpasta Thanks for the replay. I wanted only to show you a jQuery point of view